# Troubleshooting wien bridge oscillator circuit with 741 op amp

Tags: troubleshooting, wien-bridge

I built the standard Wien bridge oscillator circuit using the UA741CN op amp IC, however I am not getting any oscillation. 
[image: Schematic]

I am powering this circuit with two 9V batteries. I'm using the values R1=R2=10KΩ, C1=C2=100nF, R3 = 1KΩ, R4 = 470Ω. The oscilloscope just shows a flat line, no matter what values I try. I also tried hooking up a 8 Ohm speaker to V_OUT and circuit ground, since the oscillation amplitude and expected frequency are sufficient to make the wave audible. But there is only static.

I have tried a number of things to troubleshoot the circuit:

1. Using different resistor values, consistent with the circuit requirements.
2. Built a working [comparator circuit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=caQqOz2kz7s) using the op amp chip to ensure that the chip is good.
3. Checked all voltages.

I'm very new to electronics, so I might be missing something simple. I am wondering if somebody could provide a step-by-step guide that would eliminate any common problems with this circuit. [image]

Comment: Are you using a digital oscilloscope so that you can capture the startup behaviour of the circuit? If so, check whether the desired oscillation is present initially but decays. Please remove the breadboard photo, it isn't useful except to show that your IC power supply isn't decoupled. Place at least 100n across the supply pins as close as possible.

Comment: What voltage is your "flat line"?  (Make sure your scope is set to DC coupled). Your feedback resistors to the inverting input are a bit on the low side (10K/4.7K would be better) but basically the circuit should work. If the voltage on the output it close to zero try something more like 10K/2K for R3/R4 -- and add the bypass caps replete mentions (from each supply pin to ground). Forget about using a speaker, the op-amp is not capable of directly driving a speaker and still oscillating.

Comment: Hang on - have you calculated the expected frequency of this oscillator and compared it with the theoretical limits?

Comment: @replete - Just looking at it, it's something like 150Hz, even a 741 can manage that.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes my mistake, I calculated about 1.5Hz due to mental fatfinger.

Comment: Is the op amp powered from +9V and -9V?   Consider adding antiparallel diodes in parallel to the "R3", and making R3 slightly higher resistance than twice R4, for amplitude stability.   Try waiting, too, because the oscillation isn't self-starting, it has to build from noise.

Comment: on the face of it, 1k/470 *should* give enough gain to start oscillation, but if all components are at the wrong end of tolerance, you could easily be gain starved. Try 10k/10k, with antiparallel diodes across R3 to limit oscillation. It will make a mess of the sine wave, but at least it should start. BTW, an 8ohm load on the 741 will kill the gain and guarantee failure to oscillate.

Comment: You need to tell us the power supply arrangements. If you're running it on a single supply like a 9V battery you need to make some changes.

Comment: The UA741 has Rout of 50 to 100 ohms (that's 0.5 * 1/gm of the two output bipolar devices). If 100 ohms Rout into a 11 ohm speaker, your opamp's openloopgain is 20dB smaller than you expected. At 150Hz, unloaded Avol is 100,000/15 = 6,000. When loaded with 11 ohms, Avol is 600. But your AVCL is only "three", thus you've a 200x safety-factor.

Comment: The power supply is two 9V batteries, connected in series. Ground is the midpoint of this series. So this gives me the +/- 9V referenced to ground that is required by the chip. That's how I understand the circuit, but perhaps my understanding is in error.

Comment: I'm using a DIY digital scope. Scope is set to DC. The "flat line" is at -4V with everything connected. If I connect the speaker to the same terminals as the scope, flat line is at zero. I saw a youtube video where the speaker appears to have been connected [directly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AegxlYRKPBI), but I understand the concern about killing the gain.

Comment: Bypass caps added. No noticeable difference.

Comment: Changing the R3/R4 resistances to 10K/4.7K results in V_flatline = -7V. In contrast to -4V with the original values.

Comment: Added the regulator circuit with the diodes, but this did not change things appreciably. My guess is that I'm making a rookie mistake of some sort, so...don't assume that I'm doing the basic things right. I have rebuilt the circuit on the breadboard a couple of times, so it isn't an issue of a bad connection or something (I think).

Answer (score 1):

After much struggle and consternation, I got oscillation, by putting a 100 Ω  resistor between output (pin 6) and ground. Perhaps someone could explain why the oscillation doesn't happen without loading the output.

Comment: where did you connect the ground clip of your scope probe? what is the oscillation freq? is your scope set to dc ĉoupling? is probe set to 1X?

Comment: Ground clip is connected on the other side of the 100 Ohm resistor (i.e. to circuit ground). 220Hz. Yes. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Long inductive jumpers are about 10nH/cm and this, when coupled with positive feedback, can cause unstable parasitic oscillations at the LC resonant frequency that were limited by loading the output with high current.  It is much neater and better performance to use AWG 24 solid wire short jumpers cut to length to lay flat with the shortest distance. You end up with a small jar of odd length jumpers.

The Wein Bridge oscillator is very unstable as it is critically dependant on R tolerances.  You can overcome this by increasing the gain up to 50% and adding some soft limiting. [Example.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000150625%203.3115451958692312%2053%2015%2050%0Aa%20176%20336%20288%20336%208%208%20-8%201000000%201.1845045785514918%201.1845421213922227%20100000%0Aw%20176%20320%20128%20320%200%0Aw%20176%20352%20176%20416%200%0Ac%20176%20480%20176%20416%202%201.0000000000000001e-7%20-1.1845421213922227%0Ar%20176%20288%20288%20288%200%2027000%0Aw%20176%20320%20176%20288%200%0Aw%20288%20288%20288%20336%200%0Ar%20176%20416%20224%20416%200%2010000%0Aw%20288%20416%20288%20336%202%0Ac%20288%20416%20224%20416%202%201.0000000000000001e-7%203.556522944116992%0Ag%20176%20480%20176%20512%200%0Ar%20128%20320%2096%20320%200%2010000%0Ag%2096%20320%2096%20352%200%0AO%20320%20288%20384%20288%200%0Ar%20144%20480%20144%20416%200%2010000%0Aw%20144%20480%20176%20480%200%0Aw%20144%20416%20176%20416%200%0Aw%20176%20288%20176%20208%200%0Aw%20288%20208%20288%20176%200%0Aw%20176%20208%20176%20176%200%0A174%20288%20208%20288%20240%200%20100000%200.9950000000000001%20Resistance%0Aw%20288%20288%20320%20288%200%0Aw%20304%20224%20320%20224%200%0Aw%20320%20288%20320%20224%200%0Ad%20288%20208%20176%20208%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20176%20176%20288%20176%201%200.805904783%0Ar%20288%20240%20288%20288%200%2050000%0Ax%20236%20239%20270%20242%204%2016%20100k%0Ao%2013%208%200%2012554%208.09979710114815%200.0001%200%201%0A)

Furthermore the high Q makes the oscillator start very slow at the critical gain ratio.
 *Hence, it is rarely used outside the student lab.*
[image]

For what it's worth,  batteries are sources of noise.
Just put one an a speaker and listen.

Answer (score 0):

The output of a 741 opamp cannot drive 100 ohms. Its datasheet shows 2k minimum.
Get rid of the breadboard with the messy long wires all over the place and use a compact soldered stripboard or pcb layout.